# Dynamic module import in python (code from 3.2 to 3.3)

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, python-import, python-module

I need to dynamically import a module and create a class.
This is my working code in Python 3.2:

```
klass = {}
mod = __import__('sites.' + self.className + '_login', fromlist=[self.className])
klass[self.className] = getattr(mod, self.className)
klass[self.className](**self.args)
```

The module is inside the `sites` folder. It's called `my_site_login` and the class within that module `my_site`.

Since I upgrade to Python 3.3, the code stopped working. I read that `_____import_____` was replace by `importlib.import_module`. I tried several ways to do it but I can't get it to work.

This is what I tried:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8790051/1095101

```
mod = getattr(import_module('sites.' + self.className + '_login'), self.className)
```

I can't remember what else I've tried. What I can say, is that none of the `print()` I put right after any import attempt, was showing. I don't get any error message. It just does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to restructure this; in the `sites` package `__init__.py` file, import *all* modules that need to be imported dynamically.

Then just use attribute access instead:

```
import sites

mod = getattr(sites, self.className + '_login')
klass[self.className] = getattr(mod, self.className)
klass[self.className](**self.args)
```

If your `my_site_login.py` modules are dynamically generated, the `importlib.import_module()` callable works very simply:

```
importlib

mod = importlib.import_module('sites.{}_login'.format(self.className))
klass[self.className] = getattr(mod, self.className)
klass[self.className](**self.args)
```

From the interactive command prompt this works fine:

```
>>> import importlib
>>> importlib.import_module('sites.my_site_login')
<module 'sites.my_site_login' from './sites/my_site_login.py'>
```

Tested that in Python 2.7, 3.2 and 3.3.