# Importing dynamically all modules from a folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module, python-import

I know there is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057431/loading-all-modules-in-a-folder-in-python), but not only they're not working, it's not exactly what I want. I'm developing a racing game and want to load all tracks from a folder dynamically (They're stored as .py instead of .json). I don't want to know the names of the tracks, since users can mod/add them at will. I just want to import their data. So, for example:

```
>tracks 
>>track0.py
>>track1.py
>>track2.py
>>track3.py
>>track4.py
```

Inside each track, I have data like this:

```
track_ground_data = [
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
]
```

I need to import each track module like this:

```
loaded_tracks = [t for t in tracks] # Where tracks is the folder.
```

And then access a given `track_ground_data` like this:

```
loaded_tracks[0].track_ground_data
```

If I knew Python was going to be so harsh with its imports, I'd have used json instead .py.

Comment: Yes. I've placed that code inside a `__init__.py` file and when I try to import a track (`import tracks`): `tracks.track0`, I get an `AttributeError`.

Comment: You're right, you probably should have used a file format designed for storing data instead of executable .py files...

Comment: You could do this by adapting [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14428820/355230) to a related question about packages.

Comment: Using python files for tracks is useless if they should only contain *static* data. However they do allow to put arbitrary code, which may be a feature... for example some track could define some functions that provide specific logic for that particular track, this is way harder to do with a simple json. If you don't need the flexibility just use json files (btw: you could still import them as python modules by using a custom module loader...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python does *not* automatically import submodules contained in a package.
Hence `import tracks` **only** loads `tracks/__init__.py`.

However you *can* put code inside the `__init__.py` file that imports all the modules it finds in that directory.

For example putting something like this in the `__init__.py`:

```
import os
import importlib

__globals = globals()

for file in os.listdir(os.path.dirname(__file__)):
    mod_name = file[:-3]   # strip .py at the end
    __globals[mod_name] = importlib.import_module('.' + mod_name, package=__name__)
```

Should make your submodules available as `tracks.trackX` when importing only `tracks`.

Or you could use `exec`:

```
import os
import importlib

for file in os.listdir(os.path.dirname(__file__)):
    mod_name = file[:-3]   # strip .py at the end
    exec('import .' + mod_name)
```

---

A cleaner approach would be to use import hooks or implement your own custom module importer. There are multiple ways to do this using [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) see also [`sys.path_hooks`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html?highlight=path_hooks#sys.path_hooks)

Comment: You'd also want to filter out `__init__.py`, so only do the last statement if `mod_name` doesn't match the pattern `^__`. Something like `if not re.match(r'^__', file):`.

Answer (score 2):

Just for the sake of the good wellfare of future pythoners, I'm posting how I've solved. A friend helped me through it. Coudln't make Bakuriu's solution work, because the modules came empty. Inside `__init__.py` I've put:

```
import os

dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
modules = [os.path.splitext(_file)[0] for _file in os.listdir(dir) if not _file.startswith('__')]

tracks = []
for mod in modules:
    exec('from tracks import {}; tracks.append({})'.format(mod, mod))
```

And then, on the main file, I've loaded it as:

```
dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
sys.path.append(dir)

from tracks import tracks
```

And then:

```
loaded_tracks = [t for t in tracks]
```

That actually solved it quite well. I was almost switching to JSON / giving up.

Answer (score 1):

The problem of dynamically importing modules is faced usually when frameworks have a plug-in or add on system for the community to contribute. Each plug-in or add-on is a module containing classes and functions compliant with the framework's architecture and api.

With that in mind, the solution for "joining the dots" between the framework code and arbitrarily many add-ons is through the `importlib` present in the python standard library. You seem to face the same structural problem.

Here is a stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790003/dynamically-import-a-method-in-a-file-from-a-string) that was answered with `importlib`.
And the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html).