# Python3: different behaviour between import and importlib.import_module?

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, python-importlib

I am unable to dynamically import a module which I have no problem importing in code and I have no idea why.

I have the following:

```
> ls lib
__init__.py     main.py
```

The init file is empty. The following works:

```
> python3
Python 3.4.3 (default, Oct 14 2015, 20:28:29)
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import lib.main
>>> lib.main.sayyay()
yay
```

The following does not work:

```
> python3
Python 3.4.3 (default, Oct 14 2015, 20:28:29)
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import importlib
>>> importlib.import_module("lib.main")
<module 'lib.main' from '/some/path/lib/main.py'>
>>> lib.main.sayyay()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'lib' is not defined
```

I did read the importlib documentation as well as a couple of answers here on SO, e.g., [How to import a module in Python with importlib.import_module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10675054/how-to-import-a-module-in-python-with-importlib-import-module) and [Dynamically import a method in a file, from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790003/dynamically-import-a-method-in-a-file-from-a-string/)

But what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`import_module` returns the imported module.
Therefore, you need to give the imported module a name and use this just like `lib.main`

```
>>> lib_main = importlib.import_module("lib.main")
>>> lib_main.sayyay()
```

Comment: Oh, that was unexpected. But I see how this can be useful. Thank you.