# Asking the user to enter a function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a python program that computes the solution of f(x) =0  with Newton method, for any function. Is it possible to ask the user to enter the function?

my pseudo code :

```
# ask for a function

# create a function with: def Newton(Myfunction, initial_value)
```

Comment: The user could create a function e.g. `def f(): return None` and then assign it to a variable `my_func = f` and then pass the variable to your program (or simply pass `f`).

Comment: Please check the edit in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask the user to input the name of the python file that contains the function definition and also ask for the name of the function. Then inside your main file you can do

```
import importlib
source = importlib.import_module(filename)
func = getattr(source, function)
```

like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8790232/4419426) where `function` is the name of your user function and then call the function from your main file. You can take user input as

```
filename = input("Please enter filename containing function")
```

However there's a security risk in this method as the user can input any function from the file this way (as noted in the comment below)

Comment: I assume this method will allow for arbitrary execution of code in your program. If so, it's worth mentioning the security risk in the answer.