# Importing modules dynamically in Python 3.X

Tags: python, python-import

I would like to import a module from inside a functions. For example from this:

```
from directory.folder.module import module

def import():   
    app.register_blueprint(module)
```

To this:

```
def import():   
    from directory.folder.module import module
```

But, without hardcoding it. For example:

```
def import():
    m = "module"
    from directory.folder.m import m
```

Is it possible? Thanks in advance

Comment: I wonder what the use case is.

Comment: You want the [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib) module.

Comment: @VighneshRaut I would like to register the blueprint with Flask without every time writing down the import referred to the blueprint module.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want the [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib) module.

Here's the most simplistic way to use this module.  There are lots of different ways of weaving the results of calls to the module into the environment:

```
import importlib

math = importlib.import_module("math")

print(math.cos(math.pi))
```

Result:

```
-1.0
```

I've used this library a lot.  I built a whole plug-in deployment system with it.  Scripts for all the various deploys were dropped in directories and only imported when they were mentioned in a config file rather than everything having to be imported right away.

Something I find very cool about this module is what's stated at the very top of its documentation:

> The purpose of the importlib package is two-fold. One is to provide the implementation of the import statement (and thus, by extension, the **import**() function) in Python source code.

The intro in the 2.7 docs is interesting as well:

> New in version 2.7.
>
> This module is a minor subset of what is available in the more full-featured package of the same name from Python 3.1 that provides a complete implementation of import. What is here has been provided to help ease in transitioning from 2.7 to 3.1.

Comment: Well, that's what I always think.  But isn't this an "illegal" answer?

Comment: So, I suppose your answer is the most secure but for some reason it seems not working for my specific case. Maybe I am doing something wrong, It could be. I solved with the answer from Wasif. Thanks a lot man, I appreciated your effort and I would like that you answer will still be on the top too!

Comment: @BigMeister How about `m = getattr(importlib.import_module('directory.folder.m'), 'm')`?

Comment: @superbrain SUPERB! This is exactly what I wanted to see. Works like a charm! :D

Comment: @BigMeister That's btw from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8790232/13008439), which is an old answer for Python 2 but apparently still proper.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the importlib module to programmatically import modules.

```
import importlib

full_name = "package." + "module"

m = importlib.import_module(full_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

No, python `import` does not work this way.

Such as an example you try to import a module named `mod`, so you run `import mod`. Now interpreter will search for **`mod.py`** in a list of directories gathered from the following sources:

- The directory from where the input script was run or the current directory if the interpreter is being run interactively.
- The list of directories contained in the PYTHONPATH environment variable, if it is set. (The format for PYTHONPATH is OS-dependent but should mimic the PATH environment variable.)
- An installation-dependent list of directories configured at the time Python is installed.

So if you have a variable named `m='mod'` and run `import m` it will search for `m.py` not `mod.py`.

But just a **silly dangerous** workaround is to use `exec()` (**WARNING FOR MALICIOUS INPUT**)

```
m = "module"
exec(f'from directory.folder.m import {m}')
```

If you don't mind external modules try `importlib`.